# Append content to a ROOT file with bash?

Tags: bash

I can do

```
echo -e "foo\nbar" >> foobar
```

But I can't do:

```
echo -e "protected" >> foobar
sudo chown root:root foobar

sudo echo -e "foo\nbar" >> foobar
-bash: foobar: Permission denied
```

If I try

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "foo\nbar" >> toto'
```

I get `-e foo` in my file

Comment: Ownership and permissions are two different things. What does `stat foobar` return?

Comment: @Kenster Well I am wondering why there is 108'000  questions with the tag bash, which is not really related to programming :(

Comment: @nowox Because many, many, many people make the same mistake.

Comment: Don't use `echo`; how it works varies from shell to shell. Use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `sh` man page:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of
>   each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur
>   between  single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Try:

`sudo sh -c "echo -e \"foo\nbar\" >> toto"`

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you have full `sudo` -  does basically the same thing.
Sometimes it's nice to have options.

```
echo 'printf "%s\n" foo bar >> toto' | sudo su
```

Pipes the command `printf "%s\n" foo bar >> toto` to the sdtin of `sudo su`, which defaults to `root`. Add a user and you can execute as whomever.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the data as yourself, and use sudo to append to the file:

```
printf '%s\n' foo bar | sudo tee -a foobar
```